# How to make Qt Creator show error on no return statement

Tags: c++, qt-creator, gnu

Turns out that g++ compiler (used in Qt Creator by default) gives a mere warning if you don't have return statement in the non-void function, i.e.:

```
int* create_array(int n)
{
    int* a = new int[n];
}
```

compiles fine.

This behavior is subject to countless bug reports on g++ itself, but looks like developers consider this behavior conforming to C++ standard (which is debatable, cause it's a bit confusing in this part) as stated at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43943 :

```
Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; 
this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.
```

However, the very same paragraph begins with:

```
  A return statement without an expression can be used only in functions 
  that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type void,
  a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4).
```

So aside from these (un)holy wars over the standard interpretation are there any options to make Qt flag this as an error at compile time?

Comment: What does Qt have to do with this?

Comment: I think that lately, many developers' first experience with Qt is with QtCreator and they consider them synonymous. In this case, I believe the OP is talking about QtCreator.

Comment: @Arnold Ah yes, that would explain my confusion. Although still not a QtCreator issue but a g++ one, as Cicada answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Qt but to g++.

In the build options, simply add the flag `-Werror` and g++ will consider any warning as error. You may also need to use flag `-Wall` to make g++ generate additional warnings, as it doesn't generate warnings for missing return statements (and many other situations) by default. There's no way to tune this setting on a per-warning basis however, so it's either everything or nothing.

Comment: Where exactly should I add this in creator?

Comment: I at least know that you should be able to do it via your .pro file with something like `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Werror` Not using QtCreator though, so can't help with that.

Comment: Note that `-Werror` will make *all* warnings fatal errors, including those that might be stylistic criticisms rather than actual coding errors (especially if you also use `-Wall` (see also `-Wextra`)).  That might be what you want, but if you only want actual illegal code to cause fatal errors, take a look at `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-Werror=warning_name` syntax to treat a specific warning as an error. For your case you can use `-Werror=return-type` (where `return-type` is the name of the "control reaches end of non-void function" warning). According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html.